# Mock Debug: setting breakpoints in adapter

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Learning how to set breakpoints in a debug adapter by using [Mock Debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-debuggers) example on VSCode 1.14.0/Linux Mint 18. Following the demo instructions, I installed the Mock Debug extension and setting breakpoints on the "readme.md" worked fine. Then downloaded the .git source so I could step through the extensions.ts and mockDebug.ts. I set breakpoints in activate-"extensions.ts" and first line of each function-(mockDebug.ts). Ran the different launch types but none allowed me to hit any of the breakpoints.

Mock Debug extension has a launch.json with

```
{
   "type": "mock",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Mock Debug",
   "program": "${workspaceRoot}/readme.md",
   "stopOnEntry": true
}
```

that does allow breakpoints in the readme.md file.

How do I set up the git source version to allow me to hit breakpoints in extensions.ts and mockDebug.ts? I can not seem to hit/stop on any breakpoints I have set.

Update: Tried using debugger; command as well

> function activate(context) {
>       debugger;
>       ...
>       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have paid better attention to the docs.  After a couple hours of sleep... the VSCode Team has excellent docs on [extensions/example-debuggers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-debuggers):

```
In order to debug the debug adapter itself, we have to run it in 
debug mode. This is most easily achieved by running the debug adapter 
in 'server mode' and configure VS Code to connect to it.
```